# Selenium Web driver events

Tags: c#, selenium

how can i use selenium events. In my case, I want the program to tell me when the url chance.

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
eventDriver.Navigating += navigatedHandler;

private void navigatedHandler(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(args.Url);
}
```

the compiler does not fire any errors or exceptions. the code normally executes

Comment: When will the URL be changed ? when you click on some element and it redirects or when you do Navigations , try to call listeners after clicking     on some button or navigations.

Comment: How i use listeners?

Comment: I'll share code related to same in some time !

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an over view of **listeners**. I'll consider **WebDeriverListeners** for the example. Same you can related/mapped to **TestNG** **Listeners** if you want to.

**Why** do we use **WebDriverListeners**? -- to keep track of activity, we are doing , like after click what happens , before click what happens , before navigation and after Navigation what happens etc.

**How** you can **Implement** this behavior.
I'm using **Java+Selenium** :

First you have to create a class and that class would implement the WebDriverEventListener interface.

E.g :  Like This :

```
public class TrackActivity implements WebDriverEventListener{

    @Override
    public void afterAlertAccept(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterAlertDismiss(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1, CharSequence[] arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
         System.out.println("You have clicked on Back Button");

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
         System.out.println("You have clicked on forward Button");

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterSwitchToWindow(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertAccept(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertDismiss(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1, CharSequence[] arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeSwitchToWindow(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Now Your Test case/script container class will look like this :

```
public class StackOverFlow{

    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            EventFiringWebDriver eventFiring = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
            TrackActivity activity = new TrackActivity();
            eventFiring.register(activity);
            eventFiring.navigate().to("http://www.facebook.com");
            eventFiring.navigate().back();
            eventFiring.navigate().forward();

    }
}
```

After running this code, When ever you will navigate somewhere , respective methods related to navigation would be called because of these two methods:

```
@Override
    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
         System.out.println("You have clicked on Back Button");

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
         System.out.println("You have clicked on forward Button");

    }
```

You can do the things with TestNGListeners too.

Please let me know for related concerns.

Comment: In c# we dont have WebDriverEventListener

Comment: Yes, i know. But in c# Any examples?